# Can "call( or callonce) read" be used in the right hand side of an if evaluation, in the background?

Tags: karate

When trying to validate some mvn/runner parameters versus single scenario option, I am running into an issue with the read option.

This work is to allow testers to define the dataRow (user account info) at runtime and uses a unique authentication specific to the current feature file.  If the test is called from a runner or mvn command, we don't want every feature file to authenticate with the same user, but use the authentication called during the config initialization process.

NOTE:  there is similar code in the config to only run the authentication calls if the dsRow is present, and then save that auth result to a file to be reused by all features defined within the runner or mvn command.  This config piece is working as expected

Here is the current background that currently works as expected, for the user defined row, when running the feature file in a local manner.

```
  Background: Authentication PreRequisites 
    * def dataSourceRow = karate.get('karate.dsRow', 1)
    * def dataSourceEnv = karate.get('karate.env', 'dev')
    * callonce read('../../../../service-config.js') { dsRow: '#(dataSourceRow)' , env: '#(dataSourceEnv)' }
    
    * if (skipDomainFlag) {karate.logger.debug('skipDomainFlag is set to true so Domain calls cannot be ran!'); karate.abort(); }
    * callonce read('classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature')

    * configure afterFeature = function(){ karate.call('classpath:adapters/logout.feature'); }

    * url baseUrlDomain + domainPath
    * configure headers = domainHeaders
    * header host = domainHost
```

When trying to validate if the `karate.dsRow` was passed in, in an if statement, the subsequent read call does not appear to work as in a single line.

Here are the options I have tried:
I got the following to work, but this requires the call(once) to be on a separate line, and is not allowed in a subsequent if statement.  This works in the run of the feature file locally, but fails when running thru mvn/runner option.

```
    * if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) domainAuth = read('classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature')
    * callonce domainAuth
...
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "domainAuth" is not defined
```

Setting the callonce option behind the dsRow evaluation, results in the following

```
    * if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) domainAuth = read('classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature')
    * if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) karate.callonce('#(domainAuth)')
...
01: if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) karate.callonce('#(domainAuth)')
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js failed:
>>>>
01: read('#(domainAuth)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:19 Missing close quote
read('#(domainAuth)
                   ^

or 


    * if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) domainAuth = read('classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature')
    * if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) karate.callonce(domainAuth)
...
01: if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) karate.callonce(domainAuth)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (callonce) on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge@4af5dcab failed due to: no applicable overload found (overloads: [Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.callonce(java.lang.String)], Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.callonce(boolean,java.lang.String)]], arguments: [JavaObject[classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature (com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureCall)] (HostObject)])
```

Combining the calls into the same row, results in the same overloaded error

```
01: if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) { domainAuth = read('classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature'); karate.callonce(domainAuth) }
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (callonce) on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge@3ea98e66 failed due to: no applicable overload found (overloads: [Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.callonce(java.lang.String)], Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.callonce(boolean,java.lang.String)]], arguments: [JavaObject[classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature (com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureCall)] (HostObject)])


or 



    * if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) { karate.set('domainAuth', karate.read('classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature')); karate.callonce('#(domainAuth)'); }
...
01: if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) { karate.set('domainAuth', karate.read('classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature')); karate.callonce('#(domainAuth)'); }
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js failed:
>>>>
01: read('#(domainAuth)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:19 Missing close quote
read('#(domainAuth)
                   ^
```

It would be great if the call(once) read option would work on the right side of an if evaluation, similar to a single line option, to accommodate such situations.  If this is not a desired approach, what other options do you see, which I may have missed?

UPDATE:  Sample code to test locally
testUrl.feature

```
Feature:

Scenario:
    * def testUrl = 'http://www.google.com'
```

test.feature

```
Feature: Test for test call and callonce after a conditional
    Background: Authentication PreRequisites 
        * def testUrl = karate.get('karate.testUrl', 'http://www.bing.com')

        #**** Calls combined for troubleshooting of the call/callonce function after a conditional
        #***** uncomment only 1 of the below statements
        # * if (!(karate.properties['karate.testUrl'])) { karate.set('testUrlFile', karate.read('testUrl.feature')); karate.call('#(testUrlFile)'); }
        # * if (!(karate.properties['karate.testUrl'])) { karate.set('testUrlFile', karate.read('testUrl.feature')); karate.call(testUrlFile); }
        # * if (!(karate.properties['karate.testUrl'])) { karate.set('testUrlFile', karate.read('testUrl.feature')); karate.callonce('#(testUrlFile)'); }
        # * if (!(karate.properties['karate.testUrl'])) { karate.set('testUrlFile', karate.read('testUrl.feature')); karate.callonce(testUrlFile); }

        #**** Calls separated for troubleshooting of the call/callonce function after a conditional
        # * if (!(karate.properties['karate.testUrl'])) { karate.set('testUrlFile', karate.read('testUrl.feature')) } 
        # * if (!(karate.properties['karate.testUrl'])) { karate.log('testUrlFile is ',testUrlFile) } 
            #***** uncomment only 1 of the below statements to accompany the above 2 lines
            # * if (testUrlFile) { karate.call('#(testUrlFile)'); }
            # * if (testUrlFile) { karate.call(testUrlFile); }
            # * if (testUrlFile) { karate.callonce('#(testUrlFile)'); }
            # * if (testUrlFile) { karate.callonce(testUrlFile); }

        * url testUrl

    Scenario:
        Given path '/'
        When method GET
        Then status 200
```

Comment: `This works in the run of the feature file locally, but fails when running thru mvn/runner option.` - that shouldn't happen, so I insist on a way to replicate. I also do feel this is over-engineering and will be very hard for others to maintain in the long run. you also have a typo here: `read('#(domainAuth)')`

Comment: i will work on an example, but that may be a while to build something that is shareable.  As for the typo, I am not seeing it

Comment: As for `This works in the run of the feature file locally, but fails when running thru mvn/runner option.`, that is correct, because the call statement is needed when running locally to call the authentication.  Trying to exclude the call function like the preceding read function, appears to result in errors, shown in the subsequent lines.

Comment: may not be a typo - but I can't follow the large flow you have provided. maybe the `domainAuth` variable does not have a single-quote in it as the last line of the error message says. this is to me a case where it needs an example I can run locally

Comment: let me take a guess - please don't do this: `karate.callonce('#(domainAuth)')` and do this instead: `karate.callonce(domainAuth)` - refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: this was attempted as noted above `* if (!(karate.properties['karate.dsRow'])) karate.callonce(domainAuth)` in the second part of the "Setting the callonce option behind the dsRow evaluation, results in the following" code block results

Comment: @PeterThomas - From the example added above, you can see that call and callonce functions do not work after conditional statements.  Please try and validate if I am correct in this bug, or if I am doing something wrong.  I simply set the systemproperty check to false to trigger the conditions without having to make the calls through a runner of mvn command

Comment: it works for me. I am unable to run your example so I can't tell. it is possible that callonce is not designed to work in conditional statements, and I don't recall any team doing this or reporting this

Comment: `it works for me` - how is this working in your setups - would you mind sharing?  Unsure why you can't run the above example as it is 2 simple feature files which you uncomment the various lines in the example, and can then see the errors for both the callonce and call statements behind the conditional?  Are you using 1.3.1 with java 8 (sorry this was not specified in the post) or a different version?

Comment: added an answer with my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the source code, ScenarioBridge.java specifically, I found that instead of using a concurrent read method, to incorporate the file in the shared scope, I can simply add a boolean for sharedScope to the callonce method and that appears to have solved the issue for now...

Current working solution

```
 * if (!(karate.properties['karate.testUrl'])) { karate.callonce(true, 'testUrl.feature'); }
```

Comment: `karate.callonce()` is indeed "undocumented" because we felt it would encourage hard-to-maintain tests (as I suspect is the case here). I don't recommend it because we were actually hoping to remove it in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me, here's a simple example:

```
Feature:

Background:
* if (true) karate.callonce('called.feature')

Scenario: first
* print 'first'

Scenario: second
* print 'second'
```

Output:

```
23:52:18.580 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - >> lock acquired, begin callonce: read('called.feature')
23:52:18.586 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] in called 
23:52:18.598 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - << lock released, cached callonce: read('called.feature')
23:52:18.602 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] first 
23:52:18.606 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] second
```

Comment: So the call once appears to work if a valid string to the file is passed in, but passing variables does not appear to work, hence my issue.  I did hard code the feature file into the callonce function, `        * if (!(karate.properties['karate.testUrl'])) { karate.callonce('testUrl.feature'); }`, but this requires all variables set in the called function to not be available as they are within a different scope or have to be assigned to a variable, differently than simply being usable after a `* callonce read('classpath:testUrl.feature')` usage.  So the combination of read and callonce fails.

Comment: After looking at the code in ScenarioBridge.java, I found that instead of reading the file, I can simply add a boolean for sharedScope to the callonce method and that appears to have solved the issue for now...`        * if (!(karate.properties['karate.testUrl'])) { karate.callonce(true, 'testUrl.feature'); }`

Comment: While your solution works, it did not solve my issue.  I had to review the code to find the workaround as the scope of callonce, without a read function, is not a shared scope and that was the entire issue.

Comment: @mike I would have never guessed that the question was related to shared-scope, but okay

Comment: The question was related to using the read (which makes the call shared scope) and call/callonce after an evaluation as stated in the title and shown in the example.  Sorry sharedScope was not mentioned, but I only found that as the issue, when searching the karate source code.